# Access context menu items from windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, contextmenu, right-click

Okay I currently need to check about 200 files, so of course i want to automate as much as i can. the software I need to use to inspect them does not seem to have a command line interface, so I am currently stuck right-clicking them and clicking edit.

Is there any way to access that edit command from command line, so I can automate this process, or am I stuck opening 200 files like this.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured it out, and here's how I did it!

Go to regedit, and find the file extension im trying to deal with in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
then inside the folder for the file extension i found the name of the folder of the program this filetype uses, and that folder was also located on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

Then inside that folder is a "shell" folder wherein all of the contextual options are located.

That shell folder had an element called "edit" and that element contained a shell command that was used behind the scenes to launch the editor with the specific file.

Now I can write my batch script with this command!